# Как оптимизировать поиск взаимных лайков?

Tags: php, mysql

Пишу соц. сеть на PHP и MySQL. Сделал таблицу лайков с полями `id`, `profile_id`, `partner_id`, `date`, `read`.

Теперь нужно вытащить всех пользователей, которых я лайкнул и они меня лайкнули. То есть взаимные лайки.

Пока что у меня тянутся 2 массива: массив юзеров, которых я лайкнул, и массив юзеров, кто меня лайкнул. И потом в цикле проверяю методом перебора, взаимный ли лайк.

Как это оптимизировать?

Comment: Предположим у вас ID=1, у вашего друга ID=2, какие записи тогда будут лежать в таблице лайков в случае если вы лайкнули друг друга ?

Comment: 1 1 2 2016-05-18 14:55:59 0

Comment: 2 2 1 2016-05-18 11:20:49 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поиск таких людей для пользователя ID=1, если надо все перекрестные ссылки по всем пользователям надо убрать `where`.

```
select A.partner_id
  from likes A
  join likes B on B.partner_id=A.profile_id and A.partner_id=B.profile_id
 where A.profile_id=1
```

Если один и тот же человек может лайкать другого несколько раз (т.е. у вас в БД несколько записей с profile=X И partner=Y) то добавить `distinct` после `select` для получения уникальных пользователей

Comment: Было бы мудро запретить повторные лайки с помощью уникального композитного индекса (partner_id, profile_id). И затем без всякий проверок лайкать через оператор INSERT IGNORE.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно дважды делать выборку из таблицы:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE
  partner_id = ?
  AND profile_id IN (
    SELECT partner_id
    FROM users
    WHERE profile_id = ?
  ) AS megusta
```

Вместо `?` подставить свой id.

Ещё вариант – любой лайк рассматривать как потенциальное отношение двух юзеров, и хранить не более одной записи в таблице на любую пару:

```
uid_A  uid_B  like_AB  like_BA  date_AB   date_BA   seen_AB  seen_BA
1      2      1        1        2016-05.. 2016-05.. 0        0
```

«Договориться», что на позицию A всегда ставится юзер с мЕньшим id. Хотя искать придётся по обеим колонкам. С индексами это не проблема.

Если вырастете до миллионов, можно переехать на nosql, сделав ключом составной индекс  `uid_A<разделитель>uid_B`.